# Keytool generates different key than Keystore explorer

Tags: wildfly, keystore, keytool

I was following this tutorial on how to set mutual SSL in wildfly: 
https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/helloworld-mutual-ssl-secured


With keytool key generation, everything works fine. Then, when I try to use a client certificate generated with KeyStore explorer I get 403 (unauthorized) when I try to access the application secured by this security domain.


I've tried to find a difference in certificates or keys generated by those two tools but couldn't find one. Is there something that I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

It seems that keytool generates a different id number for CN field than KeyStore Explorer. I get the message from log that decoder could not find identifier 2.5.4.3:

```
X500 principal [CN=example, OU=asdf, O=asdf, L=asdf, ST=asdf, C=rs] was not decoded - no values of attribute [2.5.4.3]
```

Comment: How did you try to find a difference between the two generated keystores? If you haven't already, I'd suggest using `keytool -list -verbose`

Comment: KeyStore Explorer definitely sets the right OID for the CN field. It has to be something else. If you open both keystores/certificates in KeyStore Explorer, you can compare the CN field in ASN.1 view (there is a button for that in the certificate details view). Search for something like `SEQUENCE { 
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=CommonName (2.5.4.3)
                    PRINTABLE STRING='example'
                }`

Comment: Recently, I found that difference which KeyStore Explorer makes in comparison to Keytool is in the type of the CN field. Type of PrintableString works, but UTF8String doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ELY-1587 

So, I was right, KeyStore Explorer generates CN field of type UTF8String, and although WF 13 documentation claims that their decoder supports it, it doesn't.

They fixed this bug in WF 14.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: my client certificate wasn't working in Firefox but in Chrome and IE. Problem with Firefox was that strings of the certificate were encode in `UTF8String`. Recreate them with `PrintableString` was the solution, see here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1569086/firefox-does-not-offer-client-certificate-ssl-error-handshake-failure-alert